# Unable to query docker version: Get https://<ip>/v1.15/version: remote error: tls: bad certificate

Tags: docker, ssl, gitlab-ci, docker-machine, gitlab-ci-runner

I am using gitlab runner to run my tests on Digital ocean servers

After I re-installed gitlab runner I started to get the following errors:

[image]

I have the following config for my runner:

```
concurrent = 10
check_interval = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "Builds coordinator"
  url = "https://gitlab.com/"
  token = "<token>"
  executor = "docker+machine"
  limit = 10
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "alpine:latest"
    privileged = false
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
  [runners.machine]
    IdleCount = 0
    IdleTime = 0
    OffPeakTimezone = ""
    OffPeakIdleCount = 0
    OffPeakIdleTime = 0
    MachineDriver = "digitalocean"
    MachineName = "gitlab-runner-autoscale-%s"
    MachineOptions = [
        "digitalocean-image=coreos-stable",
        "digitalocean-ssh-user=core",
        "digitalocean-access-token=<token>",
        "digitalocean-region=lon1",
        "digitalocean-size=4gb",
        "digitalocean-private-networking"
    ]
  [runners.cache]
    Type = "s3"
    Path = "cache_for_builds"
    Shared = false
    [runners.cache.s3]
      ServerAddress = "ams3.digitaloceanspaces.com"
      AccessKey = "<key>"
      SecretKey = "<secret>"
      BucketName = "cache-for-builds"
      BucketLocation = "ams3"
      Insecure = false
```

I tried to do `docker-machine ls` when the build was running and I saw the following output:

```
... ERRORS
... Unknown   Unable to query docker version: Cannot connect to the docker engine endpoint
```

or

```
... ERRORS
... Unable to query docker version: Get https://<ip>:2376/v1.15/version: remote error: tls: bad certificate
```

I tried to search for certs on my server with `find -name "*cert*"` and found them in `/root/.docker/machine/certs`. I added path to the certs to the `[runners.docker]` section as described in the [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runnersdocker-section) but it didn't help:

```
[runners.docker]
  ...
  tls_cert_path = "/root/.docker/machine/certs"
```

When I view gitlab runner logs with `journalctl -u gitlab-runner` I see

```
Jan 13 21:06:59 builds-coordinator gitlab-runner[3360]: ERROR: Error creating machine: Error checking the host: Error checking and/or regenerating the certs: There was an error validating certificates for host "<ip>:2376": remote error: tls: bad certificate  driver=digitalocean name=r
Jan 13 21:06:59 builds-coordinator gitlab-runner[3360]: ERROR: You can attempt to regenerate them using 'docker-machine regenerate-certs [name]'.  driver=digitalocean name=runner-gitlab-runner-autoscale-<id> operation=create
Jan 13 21:06:59 builds-coordinator gitlab-runner[3360]: ERROR: Be advised that this will trigger a Docker daemon restart which might stop running containers.  driver=digitalocean name=runner-gitlab-runner-autoscale-<id> operation=create
Jan 13 21:06:59 builds-coordinator gitlab-runner[3360]: The default lines below are for a sh/bash shell, you can specify the shell you're using, with the --shell flag.  driver=digitalocean name=runner-gitlab-runner-autoscale-<id> operation=create
Jan 13 21:07:00 builds-coordinator gitlab-runner[3360]: WARNING: Machine creation failed, trying to provision  error=exit status 1 name=runner-gitlab-runner-autoscale-<id>
Jan 13 21:07:01 builds-coordinator gitlab-runner[3360]: Waiting for SSH to be available...                  name=runner-gitlab-runner-autoscale-<id> operation=provision
```

Before I was using gitlab runner version `11.5.1`

How can I fix these errors and make gitlab runner running the builds?